# How can we handle the key passed through URL in magento adminside using Jmeter?

Tags: php, magento, authentication, key, jmeter

How can i get the key value generated and passed through url on login into magento adminside in Jmeter or how can we handle the key passed through URL in magento adminside using Jmeter? 
As this is used for further URLs, it is not working out while recording and play back. Is there any way to bypass this or any other existing solution or settings?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into links in Magento admin page source you'll see that they're in the next form:

[image: Magento URL]

So in order to simulate request you need to extract URL Path bit.

For example, if you need to generate URL of `Manage Products` page. The best option is using [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) post processor

We need to get `href` attribute of an `<a>` link which is parent to `<span>Manage Products</span>` element

XPath expression to get `href` attribute looks as:

```
(//span[text()='Manage Products']/parent::*)/@href
```

But it'll return the whole URL with protocol, host, port, etc. like

```
http://host:port/magento/index.php/admin/catalog_product/index/key/5d35a99da0b9993d4ddce0be9a3175db/
```

My expectation that you need to To "cut off" everything after `/admin` so build a correct path. You can use [substring-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-after) XPath function as:

```
substring-after((//span[text()='Manage Products']/parent::*)/@href,"/admin")
```

Summarizing all above:

Add XPath Extractor PostProcessor as a child of the request which performs login. Configure it as follows:

[image: XPath Extractor]

- Reference name: `PATH`
- XPath query: `substring-after((//span[text()='Manage Products']/parent::*)/@href,"/admin")`
- Other fields can be left intact.

Note: Magento is using [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML), however if response is not XHTML-compliant you may have to check `Use Tidy` box in the XPath Extractor.

If you add a Debug Sampler and View Results Tree Listener you will be able to see the extracted value stored as PATH JMeter Variable:

[image: Debug Sampler]

Now you can build your next request to "Manage Products" page using extracted path and key. To do so put the following line into HTTP Request sampler Path area:

```
/magento/index.php/admin${PATH}
```

[image: Magento Path]

Save and run your test.

Voila, we're on Manage Products page:

[image: Manage Products]

See the next guides for more information and reference:

- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)
- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)